# Replace button before ajax call and then revert back after call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button on my webpage that is generated like this :

```
<div class="btn2" id="btPost" onclick="$('#Delete').val('False'); ValidateFormAndAjaxSubmit('frmEditPost', this);" onmousedown="this.className='btn2_click';" onmouseout="this.className='btn2';" onmouseover="this.className='btn2_hover';" onmouseup="this.className='btn2_hover';">
 <span>Posta</span>
</div>
```

When I have this javascript :

```
function ValidateFormAndAjaxSubmit(formId, callingElement) {

    if (IsNotDblClick(callingElement.id)) {
        var _form = $("#" + formId);

        var validator = _form.validate();
        var anyError = false;

        anyError = !_form.valid();

        if (anyError) {
            window.latestClick = '';
            return false; // exit if any error found    
        }

        $.post(_form.attr("action"), _form.serialize(), function (data) {

            if (data.success && data.redirectUrl.length > 0) {
                window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;
            }
            else {

                var isValid = validateResponse(_form, data);

                window.latestClick = '';
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is working fine, but the problem is that I want to show the enduser that the form is loading. The best solution might be to simple remove the callingElement from the webpage and replace it with a temporary disabled(special CSS) button. The button needs to return then the ajax method is done.

I know about this :

```
$("#regTitle").html("Hello World");
```

But it is only replacing inner part of the div and I do also need to store the current markup to beable to go back when the ajax call is done.

It would also be good if the text within the span is placed also on the temporary button.

The question is how I do this as simple as possible?

Comment: Can you please post the full form including the #regTitle div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it :

Generate extra hidden div under the botton like this :

```
<div class="loadingDiv" id="loadingDiv_btPost"></div>
```

with the following css :

```
.loadingDiv {
    float:                  left;
    display:                none;
    height:                 26px;
    width:                  60px;
    background:             url("images/animations/ajaxLoader.gif") no-repeat;
    background-position:    center center;
}
```

Then changed the javascript like this :

```
function ValidateFormAndAjaxSubmit(formId, callingElement) {

    if (IsNotDblClick(callingElement.id)) {

        var _form = $("#" + formId);

        var validator = _form.validate();
        var anyError = false;

        anyError = !_form.valid();

        if (anyError) {
            window.latestClick = '';
            return false; // exit if any error found    
        }

        $('#' + callingElement.id).hide();
        $('#loadingDiv_' + callingElement.id).show();
        $.post(_form.attr("action"), _form.serialize(), function (data) {

            $('#loadingDiv_' + callingElement.id).hide();
            $('#' + callingElement.id).show();
            if (data.success && data.redirectUrl.length > 0) {
                window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;
            }
            else {

                var isValid = validateResponse(_form, data);

                window.latestClick = '';
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': _form.attr("action"),
    'data': _form.serialize(),
    'beforeSend': function() {
        $('.btn2').hide();
        $('#regTitle').html('Loading ...');
        $('#regTitle').show();
    },
    'success': function() {
        $('.btn2').show();
        $('#regTitle').hide();
    },
    'error': function() {
        $('.btn2').show();
        $('#regTitle').html('Error ...');
    }
});
```